# Paperclip custom crop for rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

I've looked at numerous Paperclip cropping tutorials and I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I can't get it to work for me. The tutorials are all outdated so I'm wondering if that's the issue...

The latest tutorial I used is found [here](http://viget.com/extend/manual-cropping-with-paperclip) but the error I get is not descriptive. I get

`An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Error: There was an error processing the thumbnail for 1dc9f9eee29a7fd2f3f68e9c264b6d5420141014-13-v9mj79`

which is followed by a `Rollback` on Heroku and:

`ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template profiles/failed to update, application/failed to update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]`

I don't have any views as this is just a server side to my mobile app. I assume the latter error is not related since it shows up after the Rollback but I could be mistaken.

The data sent from my mobile app to my controller is of the form:

`Parameters: {"profile"=>{"picture1_url"=>"http://a_url_here.com/sdfsdf.jpg", "crop_x"=>384, "crop_y"=>0, "crop_w"=>201, "crop_h"=>182}, "id"=>"123"}`

And finally, my code is listed below. What am I doing wrong that is preventing me from cropping? Alternatively is it possible to pass commands into the model's `has_attached_file` so that I don't even use the processor? Something like this in my model:

```
# I tried this already and it didn't work but is there some other way to do this? 
# Also keep in mind I will need to pass variables crop_y,crop_x, etc.
has_attached_file :picture1, styles: {
  crop: "-crop '#{crop_w}x#{crop_h}+#{crop_x}+#{crop_y}" 
}
```

My actual code is listed below:

my model `profile.rb`:

```
has_attached_file :picture1, styles: {
  crop: {processors: [:cropper]}
}, url: "pictures/:facebook_id/:style/1:dotextension",
path: ":rails_root/public/:url"

attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
```

My controller `profiles_controller.rb`:

```
def profile_params
    # I have other things I permit but only showing the crop values
    params.require(:profile).permit(:crop_w,:crop_x,:crop_h,:crop_y)
end
```

My processor `cropper.rb`:

```
module Paperclip
  class Cropper < Thumbnail
    def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
      super
      @current_geometry.width = target.crop_w
      @current_geometry.height = target.crop_h
    end
    def target
      @attachment.instance
    end
    def transformation_command
      crop_command = ["-crop","#{target.crop_w}x#{target.crop_h}+#{target.crop_x}+#{target.crop_y}"]
      crop_command + super
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the processor was not recognizing `target.crop_w` etc.

I couldn't figure out how to get `target.crop_w` to be recognized in the processor.

In the end I passed the variables into the style through a lambda instance. For example:

```
has_attached_file :picture1, styles: lambda {|a| {
     crop: {processors: [:cropper], 
            crop_w:a.instance.crop_w,
            crop_x:a.instance.crop_x,
            crop_y:a.instance.crop_y,
            crop_h:a.instance.crop_h}
    }
    }
```

`a.instance.crop_w` will only exist if you set `crop_w` to the instance. So for me, in my controller I had something like

```
@profile = Profile.find_by_id(params[:id])

#
@profile.picture1_from_url(params[:profile][:picture1_url],params[:profile][:crop_w ...)
```

and `picture1_from_url` was how I downloaded images with paperclip from urls. This method is in the model like so:

```
def picture1_from_url(url,crop_w,crop_x,crop_h,crop_y)
    self.crop_w = crop_w
    #repeat above line with crop_h crop_y crop_x
    self.picture1 = URI.parse(url)
end
```

By setting `self.crop_w = crop_w` I attached that variable to the instance which is why it was accessible in `styles` with `lambda`.

Finally, by passing it like this it could be accessed in the processor through the options hash. In my processor:

```
def options
  @options
end

def transformation_command
  crop_command = ["-crop","#{options[:crop_w]}x#{options[:crop_h]}+#{options[:crop_x]}+#{options[:crop_y]}"]
  crop_command + super
end
```

And that's how I got it to work.